# Failed to resolve EFS DNS name when trying to mount on EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-efs

I'm trying to mount an EFS on my EC2 instance using the command:

```
sudo mount -t efs -o tls efs-id:/ /var/www/
```

The DNS name is not resolving.
I've already created an inbound rule on my NFS Mount security group to allow type NFS from any source.

It works perfectly if I try to mount the EFS using the command below (using IP address):

```
sudo mount -t nfs4 -o nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2 efs-ip:/ /var/www/
```

The VPC has DNS Resolution and DNS Hostnames enabled.

Comment: Just like with any AWS network problem: check the vpc, routes, subnets, security groups, NACLs. :-)

Answer (score 3):

The EFS was not in the same availability zone as the EC2 instance. Problem solved.

Comment: I have the same problem, is it necessary to create an instance in EC2?

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the different Availability zone of EFS and EC2. To resolve this I made the same availability zone for EFS.

Check the below steps:

> AWS-->EFS-->Select your EFS -->Network Tab-->Manage-->Add The AZ and
> Security Group as your EC2 instance

Answer (score 0):

I had the same symptoms (EFS IP worked but not DNS). In my case I found my (non-default) VPC didn't have *DNS hostnames* enabled. After turning that on, and waiting a few minutes, the name started resolving. [File system mount with NFS using DNS name fails](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/troubleshooting-efs-mounting.html#mount-fails-dns-name) and [DNS attributes in your VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-dns.html) were helpful.